# Stop animation at specific frame?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game with Phaser, and I need to have an animation for the health bar going down dynamically stop on a frame, and I couldn't find any clear documentation on the `stopOnFrame()` method, or the `this.anims.getFrame(index)` method, both of which woulden't work. I believe that stopOnFrame accepts a frame object, not a frame number but I coulden't figure out how to get that specific frame, as the `getFrame()` method returned undefined. If there's something I'm missing, my ideal solution looks something like this:

```
this.hpBar.play({key: 'damageAnimation', startFrame: this.hp})
this.hpBar.stopOnFrame(this.hpBar.getFrame(this.hp - amountOfDamage))
```

Thanks for any suggestions, cheers!

PS: I know there's some more nuance to how I would use the animations in forwards and reverse to properly create this effect, the example is purely for demonstration.

Comment: You may have better luck in the [Phaser Discussions](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/discussions), since this is about a specific framework

Comment: it's blocked on my school computer. I can't log in with the proxy I found, so that's a no go until my new PC comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two points, you would have to pass a `Phaser.Textures.Frame` to the `stopOnFrame` function, and as far as I know the function `getFrame` doesn't exist *(atleast on the phaser sprite GameObject, as shown in your code)*.

You can use the function `getFrameAt` on the Animation object, the index has to be here only a valid integer, in the range from 0 - to max frame of the animation.
(btw.: here is the [link to the documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#stopOnFrame__anchor) of the `stopOnFrame` function)

> **Info:** the frame index-count, is based on the **frames of the specific animation**, not the frame in the spritesheet. *(In this example the sprite frame index of the kick is `12`, but in the `kick` animation the index for that specific frame is `2`)*

**Here a Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
}; 

function preload(){
    this.load.spritesheet('brawler',
        'http://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', 
        { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
    this.load.image('brawler-sheet',
        'http://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png');
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click, to Stop on kick (third frame)')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'kick',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', 
            { frames: [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 10 ] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1,
        repeatDelay: 0
    });
    
    this.add.image(140, 20, 'brawler-sheet')
      .setOrigin(0)
        
    const cody = this.add.sprite(100, 90);
    cody.setScale(3);
    cody.play('kick');
               
    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
        cody.stopOnFrame(cody.anims.currentAnim.getFrameAt(2))
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**But** for a simple healt-bar, I would use a phaser tween, not an animation, like this you can set the value more precise, you can easily update the max-health and *"animation"* is easy.

**Here a demo how I would do it *(two visula alternatives)*:**
*(I would opt for the second version, if you have some nice heart images or so, I could find a better image for the demo)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create,
        preload
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('mushroom',
    'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/mushroom16x16.png');
}

let healthMax = 32*5
function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click, to animate healthbar')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
    
    this.healthbarBG = this.add.rectangle(10, 50, 32*5, 10, 0xffffff)
            .setOrigin(0);
    this.healthbar = this.add.rectangle(12, 52, healthMax - 4, 10 - 4, 0xff0000)
            .setOrigin(0);
        
    this.add.text(10, 75, 'Or abit more flashy')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
            
    let tilespriteBG = this.add.tileSprite(10, 100, 16*5, 16, 'mushroom')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setScale(2);
    tilespriteBG.setTint(0x2a2a2a)

    let tilesprite = this.add.tileSprite(10, 100, 16*5, 16, 'mushroom')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setScale(2);
                
    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
    
        // remove 50% health
        let newHealthWidth = healthMax * .5;
        this.tweens.add({
            targets: this.healthbar,
            width: newHealthWidth,
            duration: 750,
            ease: 'Power2',
            /* this two following properties must be remove, just for demo
            yoyo: true,
            repeat:-1*/
        });    
        this.tweens.add({
            targets: tilesprite,
            width: { to: 16 * 5 * .5, from: 16 * 5},
            duration: 750,
            /* this two following properties must be remove, just for demo
            yoyo:true,
            repeat:-1*/
        });
     })
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> modifying the `ease` and/or the `duration` property *(and others)*, you can make the animation suitable *(and spicy)* for the most usecases.